ESXI root user logon issue
We are attempting to logon to an ESXi host using the web console with the correct username and password, but it is showing that the username and password are incorrect.
Logging on using the console with the same username and password works fine.
Logging on using SSH, the same problem occurs, the username and password are  incorrect.
Can anyone help me with how I can log in using the web console GUI?
